# Fastest way to check if array contains 2 different values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Consider the following arrays:

```
['a', 'b', 'a'] //method should return true
['a', 'b', 'c'] //method should return true
['a', 'c', 'c'] //method should return false
```

I want to write a method that most efficiently checks to see if both 'a' and 'b' exist in the array. I know I can do this in a simple for loop

```
let a_counter = 0;
let b_counter = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] === 'a') {
        a_counter++;
    }
    if (array[i] === 'b') {
        b_counter++;
    }
}
return (a_counter > 0 && b_counter > 0);
```

But this isn't very short. I can do `indexOf` but that will loop through twice. I have also considered using a set as below:

```
const letter_set = new Set(array)
return (letter_set.has('a') && letter_set.has('b'))
```

But I am pretty unfamiliar with sets and don't know if this solution could potentially be more expensive than just looping. I know that `has()` operations should be faster than array iterations but constructing the set probably takes at least O(N) time (I'm assuming).

Is there a clean and efficient way to find multiple elements in an array? ES6 answers welcome

Comment: Can the person who downvoted explain why? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to do this check.

So we are saying every item must be included in the array.

```js
function contains(arr, ...items) {
  return items.every(i => arr.includes(i))
}

console.log(contains(['a', 'b', 'a'], 'a', 'b'))
console.log(contains(['a', 'c', 'c'], 'a', 'b'))
console.log(contains(['a', 'b', 'c'], 'a', 'b', 'c'))
console.log(contains(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'))
```

Comment: I really like the readability of this answer. For some reason I didn't consider using `every()`

Answer (score 3):

You could use just the [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and check if the wanted items are in the items array.

```js
const
    check = (items, wanted) => wanted.every(Set.prototype.has, new Set(items));

console.log(check(['a', 'b', 'a'], ['a', 'b'])); //  true
console.log(check(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b'])); //  true
console.log(check(['a', 'c', 'c'], ['a', 'b'])); // false
```

Answer (score 2):

```
array.includes('a') && array.includes('b')
```

`includes` seems like a real handy way to check for specific elements, even if there is more than one.

Comment: @NinaScholz I made an edit for another test case. I don't mind if there's other elements (at least for the current function I'm working on)

Answer (score 2):

Not as compact as the other examples, but it does do the job in single run.

```js
const arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'a']; //method should return true
const arr2 = ['a', 'c', 'c']; //method should return false
const arr3 = ['a', 'b', 'c']; //method should return true


const reducer = ({ a, b }, char) => ({
  a: a || char === 'a',
  b: b || char === 'b'
});

const includesAnB = arr => {
  const { a, b } = arr.reduce(reducer, {});
  return a && b;
}

console.log(includesAnB(arr1));
console.log(includesAnB(arr2));
console.log(includesAnB(arr3));
```